# @NonNull lombok failed to compile

Tags: java, lombok

Here is simple dto

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Test{
private Integer id;
private String name;
}
```

here is simple method

```
public String testName(@NonNull Test test){
return test.getName();
}
```

when i tried to build project i got an error

```
16:25:46 [ERROR] /var/jenkins_home/TestMapper.java:[59,93] cannot find symbol
16:25:46 [ERROR]   symbol:   method getName()
16:25:46 [ERROR]   location: variable test of type @lombok.NonNull Test

var test = new Test();
```

i will get same Error

Comment: Your code doesn't match your exception. That being said, your code appears not to be processed by lombok and thus no getter/setters/ have been generated.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's a compiler error message, not an exception.

Comment: Well, `test.getName` is a field access, and it should be a method call (i.e. `test.getName()`, as muratcanyeldan already said).

Comment: in code i use test.getName() and its lombok issue

Comment: do you guys even read the error message? it said cannot find symbol
16:25:46 [ERROR]   symbol:   method getName().....

Comment: Yes I read the message and I told you what the issue is. Lombok isn't processing your classes hence no getters/setters have been generated. Do you actually read the comments or only the first sentence?

Comment: i ask why and how to fix it....i do not ask obviously things like- did getters generated...

Answer (score 1):

You should update your method to this

```
public String testName(@NonNull Test test){

    return test.getName();

}
```

You should add '()' for method call.

Comment: did you read error message? it says cannot find symbol
16:25:46 [ERROR]   symbol:   method getName(), if it was field access the error will be like this cannot find symbol
16:25:46 [ERROR]   symbol:   field getName